# How to retrieve the last updated information in each row

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, data-retrieval

I have the table that is shown down below and have to retrieve the last updated code of the num, which I know by the date, but I don't really know how to retrieve that..

| num | code | created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 778951 | 1112233 | 2021-04-13 |
| 123446 | 2354654 | 2021-04-15 |
| 235487 | 1232546 | 2021-05-03 |
| 778951 | 1112234 | 2021-05-13 |
| 123446 | 2354655 | 2021-04-27 |
| 123446 | 2354656 | 2021-05-26 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by num order by created desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

An alternative method that is often a bit faster with the right indexing is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.created = (select max(t2.created) from t t2 where t2.num = t.num);
```

The right indexing is `(num, created)`.

Comment: Are there any other methods to solve that problem? I'm kind od new to the SQL and I've never heard of the window functions :(